# Accessing JSON service from localhost or file://

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest, twitter

I am making a html page intended to be run locally on a PC, preferably without a local server runing (file://). I am also using jQuery to make manipulation/AJAX a little easier.

I am trying to load 2 results from the twitter API, but I get an error. The code is as follows:

```
$.getJSON("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=someuser&count=9", {},
    function (data) {
        $.each(data.items, doSomething1);
    });
$.getJSON("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=somequery&result_type=recent&count=9", {},
    function (data) {
        $.each(data.items, doSomething2);
    });
```

I also tried the following code, but it didn't change the outcome.

```
$.getJSON("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json",
    {
        count:          "9",
        screen_name:    "someuser"
    },
    function(data) {
        $.each(data.items, updateAWTweets);
    });
$.getJSON("http://search.twitter.com/search.json",
    {
        q:              "somequery",
        result_type:    "recent",
        count:          "9"
    },
    function(data) {
        $.each(data.items, updateHashTagTweets);
    });
```

I get the following error in chrome (on a localhost server):

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=somequery&result_type=recent&count=9. Origin http://localhost:62153 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

or (with a file:// link)

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=someuser&count=9. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: That error is a cross-site scripting warning.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery.getJSON not working for twitter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183831/jquery-getjson-not-working-for-twitter)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're running into the [same-origin policy](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Same_origin_policy) restriction - your script can't access any other domain apart from the one it was loaded from.

1. You could give [JSONP](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/JSONP#JSONP) a try - that's one common solution to getting data across domains:

   - http://www.chazzuka.com/blog/?p=221
   - http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/twitter-jsonjsonp-api-url.html

   Your code would look something like this (note the addition of `callback=?` to the URL):

   ```
   $.getJSON("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=somequery&result_type=recent&count=9&callback=?", 
             {},
             function (data) {
                     $.each(data.items, doSomething2);  
        });
   ```
2. Another option is to setup a proxy - you can use Apache httpd as a proxy/reverse proxy to get around this restriction.

Comment: Seems reasonable but now I get a different error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Comment: It seems like you're trying to access the `length` property on what you think is an array but is actually `undefined`. Ensure that your data actually exists (`if(!assumedArray){//handle missing data}else{//do usual processing}`. What does Twitter return when there are no results for a search query? Also, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040069/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-length-of-undefined-jquery for some suggestions on how to debug this (and other) exceptions.

Comment: Here's a [bare-bones fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nogoodatcoding/reJN6/4/) that fetches tweets for a particular user and also displays results of a search. It that of any help?

Comment: I was just using the built-in jQuery functions and didn't access length myself at all. But nevermind, I found the solution to my asking problem, thx :)

Answer (score 6):

Add the [JQuery's JSONP callback](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/#jsonp) to the URL

```
$.getJSON("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?callback=?", {
```

Answer (score -2):

Don't use this `$.getJSON()`
Its not flexible..
You can use

```
$.ajax({
    url:"test.json",
    dataTypr:"json",
    async:false
}).responseText;
```

this can easily accessed by the html coding....