# Accessing local Json files in Javascript Windows 8 App

Tags: javascript, json, windows-8

I'm working on building a new windows 8 app using javascript.  I want to have some local json files to use as configuration files, but I'm unsure of how I can read those in to my system.

I've seen HTML5s [File Api](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) and [JSONP solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299674/accessing-json-service-from-localhost-or-file), but both seem like browser-targeted solutions.  I browsed the MSDN docs but couldn't find a MSFT API for this either.

Currently I have my configs sitting as js objects within my source, but I'd really like to separate them out.  Any suggestions?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh465199%28v=win.10%29.aspx

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967755.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the MS documentation about file access for metro apps:

[File access and permissions in Windows Store apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967755.aspx)