# JSON file not being accessed using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accessing JSON service from localhost or file://](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299674/accessing-json-service-from-localhost-or-file)

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
$.getJSON('http://game4u.comuf.com/songs.json', function(data) { 

  var output = data.music[0].url; 
  document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML = output;

});
</script>
```

But my JSON file ( music[0].url ) is not displayed in the browser when I run this. I am running the HTML on locally , not on the same server as the the website.

Comment: our JSON is invalid, there are characters in there that needs escaping also why do you have `\\` in your url?

Comment: Please can you help ? I am new to this JSON stuff :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am running the HTML on locally , not on the same server as the the website.

That would be the problem. `getJSON` is an "ajax" call, and those are limited by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Your local file system is not the same origin as `http://game4u.comuf.com/songs.json` (although some browsers treat the local file system as matching *any* origin; most don't).

If you control the content at `http://game4u.comuf.com/songs.json`, you can use [JSON-P](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP) instead of JSON. JSON-P works around the SOP. Another option is [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/), which also requires that the server end do something (in this case, grant access to origin "null") and also requires that you use a browser that supports it (all modern ones do, IE9 only does if you work around the fact it requires you to use an [XDR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ie/cc288060%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead of [XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest) object; this is something jQuery doesn't do for you although there are plug-ins that do).

---

Separately, as Musa pointed out, your JSON is invalid. It would be valid if you corrected the backslashes in the URL (they should be slashes [`/`], not backslashes [`\`]) and if you remove the trailing `,` at the end of the list, which is not valid in JSON.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. T.J. Chowder and Musa thank you. You have really helped a beginner :)